# Preg match array keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have it like this:

```
$data = array(
    "City_0" => "London",
    "City_1" => "Paris",
    "City_2" => "Lisbon",
    "City_3" => "Berlin"
    );
```

plus some other data in that same array.

User will select only one of these and what I need is:

1. Check with preg_match to get all keys that starts with "city_"
2. find key which has value (it is not empty), take that value
3. assign it to new key
4. remove all "city_" keys
5. add new key to array with the name "chosen_city" which will contain that value

What I tried:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $matches = preg_match('/city_/i', $key);

    if ($value != "") {
        $newValue = $value;

        break;
    }
}

$data['chosen_city'] = $newValue;


print_r($data);
```

This works partially, how can I remove all previous "city_" keys from array in that if statement?

NOTE:
I have other keys in array, and I don't want to remove them as well.

Input array:

```
$data = array(
        "City_0" => "London",
        "City_1" => "Paris",
        "City_2" => "Lisbon",
        "City_3" => "Berlin",
        "distance" => "5 km",
        "days" =>   "7",
        "tickets" => "2",
        "discount" => "10%",
        );
```

Expected output:

```
$data = array(
            "chosen_city" => "Berlin",
            "distance" => "5 km",
            "days" =>   "7",
            "tickets" => "2",
            "discount" => "10%",
            );
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us a expected output?

Comment: Sure, $data( "chosen_city" => "Berlin", "distance" => "5 km") One note: distance is already in array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put unset for example code :

```
$data = array( "City_0" => "London", "City_1" => "Paris", "City_2" => "Lisbon", "City_3" => "Berlin");
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $matches = preg_match('/city_/i', $key);

    if($matches && $value != ""){
        $newValue = $value;
        unset($data[$key]);
    }elseif($matches){
        unset($data[$key]);
    }

}

$data['chosen_city'] = $newValue;
```

Comment: Hey but I need to remove all of the City_ keys, after I find one City_ key which has value... I need to remove all of the City_ keys but not the other ones in the array. $data = array("chosen_city" => "Berlin", "distance" => "5 km")

Comment: can you please give me a example of your input array and your output array.   than i provide you a code

Comment: Ok i will get back to you

Comment: it still outputs City_0, City_1 even if I set them to be empty in that array... so the output is like Array
(
    [City_0] => 
    [City_1] => 
    [City_2] => 
    [distance] => 5km
    [chosen_city] => Berlin
)

Comment: Do you get my updated code?  Because when i try it will return Array ( [distance] => 5 km [days] => 7 [tickets] => 2 [discount] => 10% [chosen_city] => Berlin )  is that right?

Comment: Please Use : $data = array(
  "City_0" => "London",
  "City_1" => "Paris",
  "City_2" => "Lisbon",
  "City_3" => "Berlin",
  "distance" => "5 km",
  "days" =>   "7",
  "tickets" => "2",
  "discount" => "10%",
);

Comment: foreach($data as $key => $value){
 $matches = preg_match('/city_/i', $key);
 if($matches && $value != ""){
  $newValue = $value;
  unset($data[$key]);
 }
}

$data['chosen_city'] = $newValue;


print_r($data);

Comment: please change if condition to : if($matches && $value != ""){
            $newValue = $value;
            unset($data[$key]);
        }elseif($matches){
         unset($data[$key]);
        }

Comment: Please let me know if any query

Comment: preg_match will fail with key like 'old_man_city_horror', you need to change regexp to '/^city_/i'

Comment: or even  '/^city_\d+$/i'

Answer (score 0):

preg_* is somewhat overkill in this instance - you could use strpos and it'd work just as well

However, the question is 'how to I remove the city_* keys', so to do that, just use unset():

```
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $matches = preg_match('/city_/i', $key);

    if($value != ""){
        $newValue = $value;
        unset($data[$key]); //Remove this item from the array
        break;
    }
}

$data['chosen_city'] = $newValue;


print_r($data);
```

Comment: How can I be sure, if in future City key is added for example, City_name_2020 that will be remove, that is why I used preg_ here...

Comment: Becuase you would just be checking for a string that starts with City_ eg:

if (stripos($key,'city_') === 0) //This key is a city_ (or City_) key

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
    "City_0" => "London",
    "City_1" => "Paris",
    "City_2" => "Lisbon",
    "City_3" => "Berlin",
    "distance" => "5 km",
    "days" =>   "7",
    "tickets" => "2",
    "discount" => "10%",
);

$value = 'Berlin';
if (array_search($value, $data)) {
    $data['chosen_city'] = $value;
    foreach ($data as $key=>$val) {
        if (stripos($key, 'city_')===0) {
            unset($data[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

result:

```
array(5) {
  'distance' =>
  string(4) "5 km"
  'days' =>
  string(1) "7"
  'tickets' =>
  string(1) "2"
  'discount' =>
  string(3) "10%"
  'chosen_city' =>
  string(6) "Berlin"
}
```

If you use PHP >=5.6, probably you can use (I didn't tested this code)

```
$city = array_search($value, $data);
if ($city) {
    $data['chosen_city'] = $value;
    $data = array_filter($data,function($key,$val){return stripos($key,'city_')===false;},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
}
```